# Drupal view/rule to display nodes only to users the author of the node has flagged (followed)

Tags: drupal-7, view, flags

I'm not sure whether this is best done using Views or Rules - I'm no expert on either.

The node is a quiz and I want the quiz creator to be able to restrict access to their quiz so it's only available to those users the quiz creator have previously flagged - i.e. if I follow you, you can access my quizzes.

So far... 
I've created a View to display only quiz nodes and created a relationship to the content:author. If I  then create a relationship to bring in flag info, the available options only seem to deal with content the author has flagged not the users.

How do I bring the logged in user into the equation in order to filter the nodes by their flag status?

Or am I not on the right track trying to do it with views?

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: You need to write a custom module and check the user for flag by the author